# Python webdriver xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Im trying to verify some text displayed on the website.
Im using the following xpath, but I can't get it worked.

```
controleren = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='game_container']//font[@color='green']")
```

The HTML is displayed on the site as followed:

```
<center><table><tbody><tr valign="middle"><td style="text-align:  
center;  padding: 0; margin: 0; font-size: 40px;" align="center"     
bgcolor="red" height="60" width="60"><b> 25</b></td></tr></tbody>  
</table>Je  hebt <b>$ 1 </b>ingezet en je verdiende <b>$<font 
color="green">10</font> </b></center>
```

The font color green need to be included on the webpage. Thats what I am trying to check out,

I am learning Python. As my first script Im creating a script that helps me playing a game.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


loginnaam = "***"
password = "****"
moneytostake = "1"
casinolink = "http://www.barafranca.nl/gambling/roulette.php?casino=10"

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.implicitly_wait(15)
browser.get('http://www.barafranca.nl/') 
print ("Omerta loaded")
print ("Getting account informaiton")

#Getting in
email = browser.find_element_by_name("email")
wachtwoord = browser.find_element_by_name("pass")
email.send_keys(loginnaam)
wachtwoord.send_keys(password)
wachtwoord.send_keys("\n")
browser.implicitly_wait(15)
print ("You'\re now logged in")

#Going to roulette
browser.get(casinolink)
print ("Casino loaded")
print ("\n")
browser.implicitly_wait(15)

#The gambling part
inzetten = browser.find_element_by_name("b")
inzetten.send_keys(moneytostake)
inzetten.send_keys("\n")

controleren =    
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='game_container']    
//font[@color='green']")    

if controleren.is_displayed():
bedrag = 1
else:
bedrag = (bedrag * 3)
```

Comment: You did not post full html.?

Comment: Where is your `div` having `id="game_container"`? You can also add the HTML on multiple lines. It will be easier to read it.

Comment: Why you need selenium in first place? If the website using `ajax` calls then it is needed or even if you want to find some text use something like `anything = Selector(text=self.browser.page_source)` you can find anything in it

Comment: I will post my entire script to give you an idea.